# How to play MP4 video from System.IO.Stream in WPF App?

Tags: wpf, video

I'm developing a WPF based app in C# and I want to play an h.264/aac encoded mp4 file from a stream source that derives from System.IO.Stream.

I can play videos directly from local files, and from a URL source, but I also need to playback video from a data source that derives from System.IO.Stream. Specifically, I'm using a product from Eldos called Solid File System (http://eldos.com/solfs/) which allows you to create virtual file systems inside a single file. To access data stored inside a SolidFS file they offer SolFSStream which derives from System.IO.Stream.

Does anyone know of a .Net Framework API, or third party API that will allow me to play the video by passing in the stream reference?

Answer (score 0):

My preference would be to copy the files to a temp directory that the application can access, then use a simple to use and robust library to play the file e.g http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.aspx

My reasoning would be that supporting stream may not be the best criterea to choose a third party library to play mp4 files. You need to ensure that the library is robust and easy to integrate with your existing application.

Please note, by referring to the MediaPlayer class I am not saying that this is the most robust library, but it has met my use cases in the past and was easy to integrate with the application.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but to copy the video out to a temp folder is not an option for a range of security reasons. In addition, who wants to wait for a 3.7GB file to be copied before their file can begin playing.

Comment: Hey Robb, we have similar requirement. Did you find a solution to play the mp4 from a stream?

Answer (score 0):

DirectX had some methods to play custom streams, but I don't know details. Also, we offer OS edition of SolFS for usage scenarios like yours - you can have a virtual disk with OS edition and play from there (and disk access can be restricted to only your application and the player for security).